# How to print Unicode like “u{variable}” in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

For example, I can print Unicode symbol like:

```
print u'\u00E0'
```

Or

```
a = u'\u00E0'
print a
```

But it looks like I can't do something like this:

```
a = '\u00E0'
print someFunctionToDisplayTheCharacterRepresentedByThisCodePoint(a)
```

The main use case will be in loops. I have a list of unicode code points and I wish to display them on console. Something like:

```
with open("someFileWithAListOfUnicodeCodePoints") as uniCodeFile:
    for codePoint in uniCodeFile:
        print codePoint #I want the console to display the unicode character here
```

The file has a list of unicode code points. For example:

```
2109
OOBO
00E4
1F1E6
```

The loop should output:

```
℉
°
ä
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an exact example of the output you want? It's not clear what you want, but it *might* be `unicodedata.name(a)`.

Comment: Can't you just pass `a = u'\u00E0'` to the function?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but If you're trying to print the contents of a unicode text file, I think your current code should work.

Comment: @chepner I've added sample input and output in the question.

Comment: @Colin No, I can't do that because I don't have the string literal '00E0'. This literal is in a variable. For example a = '00E0'. If it were a string literal I could do it like u'\u00E0'. But since I have a variable I need to do something like a = u + "\u"+codePointVariable. Which is not a valid call since the unicode indicator "u" doesn't work like that in a statement.

Comment: OK, my guess was way off, but it is clear now what you want.

Comment: @Colin Ok. I gave it a try. This is what I did.
    `b = "00E0"`
    `print unicode(b) # outputs 00E0`

    `c = "\\u"+b`
    `print unicode(c) # outputs \u00E0`

This is not what I want. I want it to output this character -> `à`

Comment: How is this file formatted? Is it ascii hex digits representing code points? Or is it some binary unicode encoding, like say, UTF-16?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, it is ASCII.

Comment: You could do `data = b"\\u".join(line.strip() for line in open("file", "rb"))).decode("unicode-escape")` but there is likely a better way.

Comment: If this was an ascii hex encoding of utf-16 you could undo the hex with `binascii.unhexlify` but that would mess up encodings that need extended characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a great way, but it's a start:

```
>>> x = '00e4'
>>> print unicode(struct.pack("!I", int(x, 16)), 'utf_32_be')
ä
```

First, we get the integer represented by the hexadecimal string `x`. We pack that into a byte string, which we can then decode using the `utf_32_be` encoding.

Since you are doing this a lot, you can precompile the struct:

```
int2bytes = struct.Struct("!I").pack
with open("someFileWithAListOfUnicodeCodePoints") as fh:
    for code_point in fh:
        print unicode(int2bytes(int(code_point, 16)), 'utf_32_be')
```

If you think it's clearer, you can also use the `decode` method instead of the `unicode` type directly:

```
>>> print int2bytes(int('00e4', 16)).decode('utf_32_be')
ä
```

Python 3 added a `to_bytes` method to the `int` class that lets you bypass the `struct` module:

```
>>> str(int('00e4', 16).to_bytes(4, 'big'), 'utf_32_be')
"ä"
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! But I hope somebody posts a simpler way too. This is way too complicated for my level. Thanks a lot! I'll use this for now.

Answer (score 3):

You want `print unichr(int('00E0',16))`. Convert the hex string to an integer and print its Unicode codepoint.

Caveat: On Windows codepoints > U+FFFF won't work.

Solution: Use Python 3.3+ `print(chr(int(line,16)))`

In all cases you'll still need to use a font that supports the glyphs for the codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

These are unicode code points but lack the `\u` python unicode-escape. So, just put it in:

```
with open("someFileWithAListOfUnicodeCodePoints", "rb") as uniCodeFile:
    for codePoint in uniCodeFile:
        print "\\u" + codePoint.strip()).decode("unicode-escape")
```

Whether this works on a given system depends on the console's encoding. If its a Windows code page and the characters are not in its range, you'll still get funky errors.

In python 3 that would be `b"\\u"`.